# Rails meta tags gem title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-tags

Using Meta-Tags gem, in my blog post show page this piece of code prints the code itself instead of showing its value, which is the blog post title!

```
<% title '#{@blog_post.title}' %>
```

What's wrong with it? Seems like such easy problem but haven't come up with a solution yet!

Comment: single quoto does not work in `#` tag

Comment: To print in ERB you need to use  `=` such as: `<%= @blog_post.title%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <% title "#{@blog_post.title}" %>
```

Comment: Damn it. I knew it's going to be ridiculous. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have ruby interpolation, then you need to use double quotes, not single quotes.

Try changing this:

```
<% title '#{@blog_post.title}' %>
```

to this:

```
<% title "#{@blog_post.title}" %>
```

Then it should work.